# How can I support a split view in landscape on the iPhone 6 or 5s?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

In my app there's a lot of wasted space in landscape on the iPhone 6, and to a lesser extent even on 4" screens. I'm already using iOS 8's UISplitViewController changes to support the two-pane view in landscape on the iPhone 6 Plus, but it'd be useful to see both panes on some smaller devices as well.

Conveniently Apple had a WWDC 2014 session, ["Building Adaptive Apps with UIKit"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/#216-video) which included details on exactly how to do this. You can [download the sample code here](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/resources/sample-code/), but in short: they put the `UISplitViewController` inside of a `UIViewController` subclass. The subclass uses `setOverrideTraitCollection:forChildViewController:` to force `[UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular]` on the split view when it considers the width wide enough. At the time the sample code worked well, and still does on most devices.

However after attempting to use this code in my own app, I discovered it fails horribly on the iPhone 6 Plus. You can see this yourself if you download the sample code and make two changes:

- Add a storyboard, add an empty view controller to that, and set it as the "Launch Screen File". This is necessary to run the app at its native resolution on the 6 Plus.
- In `AAPLTraitOverrideViewController.m`, change line 21 to `size.width > 500.0`, or anything greater than 414. This is necessary to ensure the split view only shows a single view in portrait on the 6 Plus.

Now you can run the app in the simulator. To see the problem, just do this:

- Rotate the device to landscape (command-right arrow)
- Rotate it immediately back to portrait (command-left arrow)

You can already see that something's not right. All of the table cells should have an arrow on the right side in portrait, but they don't. They're behaving like they're still in a split view. If you tap one of those rows, it gets worse—the detail view slides up from the bottom, and the navigation bar is gone.

I think there must be a bug in iOS 8 here that's causing the problem. But since this code was shared before the iPhone 6 Plus was announced, it also seems possible that it just needs some adjustments to make it compatible with that device. So far the only solution I've found is to change line 21 to something like `if (size.width > 500.0 && size.width < 736.0)` but I don't want to use code that could break again the next time Apple introduces a new screen size. Is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like you'll always want to make the horizontal size class regular (`UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular`). To do this, override `traitCollectionDidChange:`. In this method, if the vertical size class is `compact` (suggesting it's likely in landscape), override the trait collection so that the horizontal size class is regular.

```
UITraitCollection *compactHeight = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithVerticalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact];
if ([self.traitCollection containsTraitsInCollection:compactHeight]) {
    UITraitCollection *regularWidth = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular];
    self.forcedTraitCollection = [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithTraitsFromCollections:@[self.traitCollection, regularWidth]];
    [self setOverrideTraitCollection:self.forcedTraitCollection forChildViewController:_viewController];
} else {
    [self setOverrideTraitCollection:nil forChildViewController:_viewController];
}
```

However, if you'll want more specific behavior, you'll have to rely on canvas size for app-specific behavior.

Comment: Excellent. I changed your height check to `(self.view.bounds.size.width > 500.0)` and it seems to be working how I want it to. (I definitely don't want a split view on 4S, and 5S might be pushing it a bit.) It's interesting that this doesn't seem to exhibit the same bug even though it ultimately does the same override of the trait collection. Out of curiosity why are you combining self.traitCollection and regularWidth? It seems like just using regularWidth for the override accomplishes the same thing?

Comment: @Matt is it possible to enable this on iPhone 6 too?

Comment: @Besi certainly. The same thing will work. Just override the trait collection for iPhone 6 to be regular instead of compact.